# KNIME: Saving workflow stuck at Weka Predictor Internals

Tags: knime

It's the x-th time that saving my KNIME workflow gets stuck at "Weka Predictor (3.7) - Internals". It is always a Weka node blocking the saving process, eventually I have to force KNIME to quit and lose my changes.

My memory status is roughly 900MB out of 3300 currently, 6000MB being the maximum allowance for my Java VM. KNIME gets 5% of my CPU power, nothing else is running.

Anybody experiencing the same problem? Any advice or solution?

Comment: Is it realy stuck, or is the model just realy large?

Answer (score 1):

In Files > Preferences > KNIME > KNIME GUI you may want to turn Console View Output Level to "DEBUG" and see if anything interesting / helpful in the output console.